# php ldap not logging in

Tags: java, php, ldap

I have php ldap login page look like this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){

    $adServer = "ldap://ldap.somedomain.com:389";

    $ldap = ldap_connect($adServer);
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $ldaprdn = 'o=mycompany' . "\\" . $username;

    ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
    ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

    $bind = @ldap_bind($ldap, $ldaprdn, $password);


    if ($bind) {
        $filter="(sAMAccountName=$username)";
        $result = ldap_search($ldap,"dc=MYDOMAIN,dc=COM",$filter);
        ldap_sort($ldap,$result,"sn");
        $info = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $result);
        for ($i=0; $i<$info["count"]; $i++)
        {
            if($info['count'] > 1)
                break;
            echo "<p>You are accessing <strong> ". $info[$i]["sn"][0] .", " . $info[$i]["givenname"][0] ."</strong><br /> (" . $info[$i]["samaccountname"][0] .")</p>\n";
            echo '<pre>';
            var_dump($info);
            echo '</pre>';
            $userDn = $info[$i]["distinguishedname"][0]; 
        }
        @ldap_close($ldap);
    } else {
        $msg = "Invalid email address / password";
        echo $msg;
    }

}else{
?>
    <form action="#" method="POST">
        <label for="username">Username: </label><input id="username" type="text" name="username" /> 
        <label for="password">Password: </label><input id="password" type="password" name="password" />        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
<?php } ?>
```

keep getting this error:

```
Invalid email address / password
```

I have a java ldap code that is working fine to login to the server:

```
String oldicnumber;
String newicnumber;
String sn;
String mail;

public boolean userIsValid (HttpServletRequest request, ServletContext application, String userid, String password)
throws java.io.IOException
{
  sainserp_servlet.Logger logger = new sainserp_servlet.Logger(request); 

  String url = "ldap://ldap.somedomain.com:389";

  Hashtable environment = new Hashtable();
  environment.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
  environment.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, url);

  if (password.equals("")) {
    logger.setPath(2);
    logger.WriteLogFile("Ldap userid: "+userid+"  \t exc: no userid or password apply\n\n");
    return false;
  }
  else {
      try {
                DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(environment);
                if (ctx == null ) {
                logger.setPath(2);
                logger.WriteLogFile("Ldap userid: "+userid+"  \t exc: DirContext ctx == null\n\n");
                return false;
                }

                SearchControls constraints = new SearchControls();
                constraints.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
                //search mycompany subtree for uid
                NamingEnumeration results = ctx.search("o=mycompany", "uid=" + userid, constraints);

                if ((results != null) && results.hasMore()) {   //can be found
                SearchResult si = (SearchResult)results.next(); //retrieve results
                environment.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION,"simple");
                environment.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, si.getName()+",o=mycompany");
                environment.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
                DirContext dirctx = new InitialDirContext(environment);
                if (dirctx == null) {
                logger.setPath(1);
                logger.WriteLogFile("Ldap userid: "+userid+"  \t exc: DirContext dirctx == null\n\n");
                return false;
                }
                String[] attrOLDIC = {"oldicnumber"};
                String[] attrNEWIC = {"newicnumber"};
                String[] attrSN = {"sn"};
                String[] attrMAIL = {"mail"};


                Attributes name = dirctx.getAttributes(si.getName()+", o=mycompany", attrSN);
                sn = (String)name.get("sn").get();

                } else {
                logger.setPath(2);
                logger.WriteLogFile("Ldap userid: "+userid+"  \t exc: username not found\n\n");
                        return false;       //username not found
                }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (e.toString().indexOf("Invalid Credentials") >= 0) {
        logger.setPath(2);
        logger.WriteLogFile("Ldap userid: "+userid+"  \t Error: Invalid Credentials\n\n");
                return false;
      } else if (e.toString().indexOf("No Such Object") >= 0) {
        logger.setPath(2);
        logger.WriteLogFile("Ldap userid: "+userid+"  \t exc: No Such Object\n\n");
                return false;
      } else {  

        logger.setPath(2);
        logger.WriteLogFile("Ldap userid: "+userid+"  \t exc: " + e + "(unknown exception)\n\n");
                return false;
            }
        }
    logger.setPath(2);
    logger.WriteLogFile("Ldap userid: "+userid+"  \t Ldap login success\n\n");
    return true;
  } //end if password = null
} //userIsValid
```

I am able to to get the true status if I call the java function like this:

**userIsValid(request, application, userid, password);**

How do I get the php code to work, I think it require to put something like:

```
environment.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION,"simple");
environment.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, si.getName()+",o=mycompany");
```

Comment: Could you change @ldap_bind to ldap_bind and take a look at the provided error message if any?

Answer (score 0):

manage to sort it by add this at java code

```
System.out.println("  si.getName() : "+ si.getName());
```

my php code altered to:

```
$ldaprdn = "uid=$username,o=Company1,o=Company2";
```

solved the problem.